# It is possible to set cmake arguments per ABI in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, cmake

I have a crossplatform library with cmake based build script. Since cmake support for android is available now (https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html), I plan to move ndk-build makefiles to the trash.

I've tested `find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)`
and it working well, because zlib headers and library itself is available for all ABI's in NDK sysroot.
So, I can add any custom argument to cmake cmdline per flavor or build type:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DMYLIB_ENABLE_PROGUARD=ON"
            }
        }
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DMYLIB_ENABLE_PROGUARD=OFF"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is in ability to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` per ABI to find external static/shared libs via FindPackage.

Generally, I can use `find_library` and `include_directories` in conjunction with `${ANDROID_ABI}` in cmake script itself, but I already have working script with multiple platform support, I don't wan't to add dirty code, because there is the clean way (find_package + CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH).

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 5):

This is not something that we currently support. I think it should be possible though. I opened b.android.com/225884 to track it.

Comment: The issue tracker mentions about a gross workaround. But what is the workaround?

Comment: I believe it was to make distinct configurations for each abi, so for example, debugx86 { ndk { abiFilters "x86" } } and so on, one per ABI

Comment: The bug seems to be no longer accessible. maybe this answer should be replaced with the implemented solution

Answer (score 4):

if you are just after ABI you can do things like

```
if(${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "x86_64")
    # ABI xx
endif()
```

This works very well and does not feel like a hack. I use it for building OpenSSL (complete usage here: https://github.com/schwabe/platform_external_openssl/blob/icsopenvpn/openssl.cmake)

If you need really flavours... I came up with this super ugly hack for flavours:

```
cmake
# Super hacky way to determine if flavour is normal
# cmake is called with the DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY that includes the flavour (and archtecture)
#-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/arne/software/icsopenvpn/main/build/intermediates/cmake/normal/debug/obj/arm64-v8a
if (${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} MATCHES "build/intermediates/cmake/.*normal.*/")
  # Flavour specific
endif()
```

Comment: The given link seems to be dead, one may try [link](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/blob/master/main/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt#L110) instead as of today.

Comment: corrected the link